# Mysqli fetch() is not fetching data

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to fetch some data from a statement. Below is the code and it works until `bind_result()`. I have checked every other step only thing not working is the `fetch()`. I tried to fix it for hours before posting here. I hope someone helps. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['login'])) {

    // Get form inputs to variables
    $username = strip_tags(trim($_POST['admin-email']));
    $password = strip_tags(trim($_POST['admin-password']));

}

// If username and password is set
if (isset($username, $password)) {

    // New db connection
    $mysqli = new mysqli($servername, $dbusername, $dbuserpasswd, $dbname);

    // Check db connection is set
    if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
        die("Database connection failed: " . $mysqli->connect_error);
    }

    // Prepare select query
    $query = "SELECT admin_email, hashed_password FROM admins WHERE admin_email =?";

    // Init statement
    $stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();

    // Prepare statement
    if (!$stmt->prepare($query)) {
        print "Failed to prepare the statement";
    }
    else {
        // Bind parameters to statement
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);

        // Execute statement
        if (!$stmt->execute()) {
            print "Failed to execute statement";
        }
        else {
            // Get results to a variable
            $results = $stmt->get_result();

            // Check if user exists
            if ($results->num_rows > 0) {

                // Bind variables to prepared statement
                $stmt->bind_result($username, $hashed_password);

                // Fetch from statement
                if (!$stmt->fetch()) {
                    print "Failed to fetch from statement";
                }
                else {
                    // Verifiy input password with hashed password on database
                    if (password_verify($password, $hashed_password)) {
                        echo "It's wrong!";
                    }
                    else {
                        echo "It's correct!";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: **Warning:** Don't run `strip_tags()` on passwords. You don't need to do anything with the password except hashing it. That could change the password considerably. Imagine someone with the password: `<locats />`, stripping the tags would leave you with an empty string, making the password completely blank for that user

Comment: Thank you. I will remember that. Any idea why the fetch() is not working? Is there something wrong with the way I'm doing a `bind_result()` here?

Comment: _Suggestion:_ If you're in the beginning of building your application, I would suggest that you switch to PDO instead of Mysqli, since it has a much cleaner and easier API to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're binding variables to a statement you need to store results on the same statement instead of getting results to a different variable.

So instead

```
$results = $stmt->get_result();
```

Use below

```
$stmt->store_result();
```